# Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’

Tags: angular, google-chrome, spring-boot, firefox, xmlhttprequest

My application do some REST request in a java web application. the requests are CORS requests so the browser do every time an OPTION preflight before the real one.
Each request are similar to

> Host: localhost:8080 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64;
>   x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: iv-groups,iv-user,x-xsrf-token Origin:
>   http://localhost:4200 Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: max-age=0

The java application response is:

> HTTP/1.1 200  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=70A5ED7E8D32DCEE55991D3945994AB0;
>   Path=/blablab; HttpOnly Set-Cookie:
>   XSRF-TOKEN=35ad4230-b664-400c-84c0-7d06877bf05d; Path=/ Vary: Origin
>   Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method Vary:
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
>   http://localhost:4200 Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
>   GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
>   iv-groups, iv-user, x-xsrf-token Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:
>   true Access-Control-Max-Age: 1800 Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE,
>   TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store,
>   max-age=0, must-revalidate Pragma: no-cache Expires: 0
>   X-Frame-Options: DENY Content-Length: 0 Date: Thu, 22 Nov 2018
>   08:31:18 GMT

For firefox this response is an CORS violation on the console it writes Credential is not supported if the CORS header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*`.

For google chrome the request is ok and the content is showed.

Answer (score 5):

That happens if you are using **withCredentials** in your client side request. In that case you can modify the server side to check allowed referers and send the correct url in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. If you do not use credentials * is accepted.

Some more information can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: But how you can see the server response contains in the header
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
and not
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

In google chrome always is ok but in firefox seems the problem is always there.

Answer (score 3):

For everyone coming here searching for this issue:

I had an extension installed ([CORS Unblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-unblock/)) which had overwritten the headers. Turning that off or uninstalling it removed the problem.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't log into twitter and I really doubted that no Firefox user could log into twitter. I'm working on code locally and I installed a CORs Unblock extension so I could get it to run locally. So, I wish the big browsers would implement more options for CORs, like a white list, or the ability to turn it off for localhost.

Answer (score 0):

This config worked for me. Pay attention in client side `withCredentials: true`

**Client side config:**

```
config = {
    url:'http://somedomain',
    method:'post',
    withCredentials: true,
    data:{myfield:"myvalue"}
};

axios.request(config);
```

**Server side config:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials   true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers  X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 // WILD CARD WILL NOT WORK WHEN POSTING
```

Comment: The server response in the question shows `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200`